# Что общего между словом "противно" и названием города Протвино?

Tags: прилагательные, названия

Я заметил, что пользователи Интернета очень часто в названии города Протвино переставляют местами буквы В и И и получается слово "противно".

Comment: Тагир, скорее всего, буквы переставляет автозамена: слово "противно" более частотно, чем название города.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Протва — Протв/ин/о,*** куда же яснее-то?

С другой стороны, **ПроТ/Вино и ПроТ/Ивно.** Звуки-то одни и те же, только местами поменялись. Вероятно, местным жителям такое произношение удобнее.

Скорее всего, это **реку́рсия** (или о́тступ) в фонетике. Во время рекурсии произносительные органы речи переходят в положение, необходимое для производства следующего звука (в данном случае звука И).

Еще интересный пример: **неРВы — неВРалгия**. Этот вариант закреплен в письменной речи.

А еще некоторые люди говорят — **транвай**. Вместо — трамвай! Откуда это пошло?! И даже объясняют: трамвай им  напоминает слово "травма". Вероятно, Михаила Александровича Берлиоза все забыть не могут.

А еще говорят коклета, паликмахерская, пинжак и т.д.

Тему можно почитать здесь [Понятия комбинаторной фонетики: аккомодация, ассимиляция, диссимиляция и др](https://studopedia.su/13_144955_ponyatiya-kombinatornoy-fonetiki-akkomodatsiya-assimilyatsiya-dissimilyatsiya-i-dr.html)

Comment: **Анаграмма** — именно так называют явление, когда в исходном слове переставляют буквы местами и получается другое слово с тем же количеством букв, чем исходное слово.

Comment: Так это это была загадка? Класс!

Answer (score 2):

Ничего. Название города Протвино произошло от названия реки Протвы. Со словом «противно» это никак не связано.